# asp.net grid view show with ConvertTimeFromUtc

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDS1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:phiSQL %>"                
SelectCommand="select ID, AnalasisDate from ProgTbl  "></asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDS1" Width="1200px"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"  OnRowCommand="GridView1_OnRowCommand" 
    AllowSorting="True">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID"  HeaderText="Identification"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="AnalasisDate"  HeaderText="Time Stamp"/>
         ...
```

I need to convert the Analasis date to the the following:

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(result.AnalasisDate.Value, tz).
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do this in the aspx.cs file so that it shows the ConvertTimeFromUtc version when it displays.

I was wondering if there was something I could do in `GridView1_RowDataBound` to update the value of AnalasisDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in markup with `TemplateField`:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Time Stamp">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Eval(result.AnalasisDate), GetTimeZone()) %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Here `GetTimeZone` is a protected or public method, that should be declared in code behind class and return the necessary time zone.

Alternatively you can leave all the conversion logic to the code behind function, say `ConvertFromUtc`, and call it inside the `<ItemTemplate >`:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Time Stamp">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# ConvertFromUtc(Eval(result.AnalasisDate)) %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```